# Unable to get button value with loop Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working with jquery and PHP,I want to display "buttons" according to database value(dynamic) and want to get button values in jquery, I am using "input type hidden", But right now getting value="1"(static), But I want to get "correct" value (if I select button 2 then 2 value should get in jquery)

Here is my HTML code

```
<?php $j=$records['start_range'];
    $max= $records['end_range'];
    for($i=$j;$i<=$max; $i++) { ?>
<button class="btn btn-scale btn-scale-asc-<?php echo $i; ?>">
<?php echo $i; ?>

<input type="hidden" <?php if($records['IsRatingQuestion']=="" || empty($records['IsRatingQuestion'])){ ?>name='ques_<?php echo $records['ques_id']; ?>' <?php } else{ ?>name='rangeR_<?php echo $records['ques_id']; ?>' <?php } ?> id="ratings" value="<?php echo $i; ?>">
                                    
</button>
<?php } ?>
```

Here is the script, Where I am wrong?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#next1").click(function(){
 var rating =$("#ratings").val();
                alert(rating);                                  
        });
 });
 
</script>
```

Comment: where is `next1` element? Also ,you cannot use same ids instead change them to `class="ratings"`

Answer (score 0):

Before anything else, you need to remove `input` from inside that `button`. It's not a valid HTML.
Moreover, as mentioned in the comments, you cannot have the same id for all `inputs`, so I'd just remove it.

How about something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.item').each(function() {
    var $button = $(this).find('button')
    var $input = $(this).find('input')
    
    $button.click(function() {
      alert($input.val())
    })
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <button>1</button>
  <input type="hidden" value="1">
</div>
<div class="item">
  <button>2</button>
  <input type="hidden" value="2">
</div>
<div class="item">
  <button>3</button>
  <input type="hidden" value="3">
</div>
<div class="item">
  <button>4</button>
  <input type="hidden" value="4">
</div>
```

Comment: @kanika I updated the answer to use a sample static HTML, so you can see that the javascript is working. It might be something inside your php loop.

Comment: actually i want button value after click on another button ( Next) and my button value is not staic , my buttons value is dynamic ( coming from database)

Comment: @kanika Could you update your source showing the `next` button ? And also, if you're not clicking `<button class="btn">`, why do you need it as a `button` element ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am understanding, you just want to show the value of the dynamic button using jquery. For this you just need to pass the value to the button using data attribute and then you can get the value using jquery.

```
<?php $j=$records['start_range'];
$max= $records['end_range'];
for($i=$j;$i<=$max; $i++) {
    echo '<button class="get-value" data-value="'.$i.'">Button '.$i.'</button>';
} ?>

<input type="text" id="show-value">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.get-value', function(){
        var button_value = $(this).data('value');
        $('#show-value').val(button_value)
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) is a jquery method. Since your code never sets it, it will always return undefined.

Comment: Yes .data() is jquery function but we can use it in HTML fields to pass extra values except value attribute and in my code I have used it in button tag to set the dynamic values. Thereby it can be accessed by jquery .data() method, so it will not return undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think putting an `<input>` inside of a `<button>` is valid html (although it seems to work?). Instead you can just assign those values as attributes of the button itself. Also `id`s have to be unique, so if you have a bunch of buttons with the same id, that is also invalid. I tend to stay away from ids and just use classes to avoid this.

Also, rather than having a bunch of choppy php, you can build a single string of html and echo it back all at once. By using double qoutes `"` on the outside of a string, you can use single quotes `'` on the inside and drop variables right into the string without escaping or concatenating anything. Although you have to wrap associative arrays in brackets `{}` for it to parse correctly. [PHP strings.](https://www.php.net/language.types.string)

I'm guessing `$name` isn't a static variable, but without seeing the rest of your code, this is just an example:

```
<?php
  $html = "";
  $name = ($records["IsRatingQuestion"] == "" || empty($records["IsRatingQuestion"])) ?
    "ques_{$records["ques_id"]}" :
    "rangeR_{$records["ques_id"]}";

  for($i = $records["start_range"]; $i <= $records["end_range"]; $i++) {
    $html .= "<button class='btn btn-scale btn-scale-asc-$i ratings' name='$name'>$i</button>";
  }

  echo $html;
?>

  

$('.btn.ratings').on('click', function() {
  //$(this).text() = $i
  //$(this).attr('name') = $name
});
```